# How to set default video playback resolution on Google+?

Tags: google-chrome, video, google-plus

I've been using google plus to host and share videos lately and I really like it. Unfortunately when I click to play back a video it defaults to 360p when 720p is available.

Is there some way to set the default to HD or a Chrome browser extension to select 720p automatically like you can do on Youtube?